# Using !important with multiple stylesheets for different color schemes

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm developing a WordPress theme and I'd like to include multiple color schemes, each with its own stylesheet. I don't want to exclude every property pertaining to color from the base css file and force a second file to be loaded even for the default scheme. If I were to simply include the base color scheme in the main stylesheet, and then use !important on every color property on the alternate stylesheets, would that be considered bad practice? It seems like gratuitous use of !important, but I'm not sure if it's acceptable or not.

Comment: The use of a preprocessor (LESS or Sass) would allow to define colors in variables and to compile each theme (with Prepros or any other server side tool) as a different stylesheet with only the colors for this theme, not even the default ones. That's just one way of doing it. You don't gain too much performance because 2 different rules with only the value differing will GZip well, but maintenance would gain from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the idea of important, to override all other matching css rules.

However it's better if you find another way to override the base style rather than using !important.

You should use the !important only when there is no other way (for example to override inline styles).

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Perhaps you can override the base class, or perhaps you can add one class before the other:

```
<p class="base_class theme_class">Bla Bla Bla</p>
```

I.e. have "base_color theme_color" and only implement theme color in the second theme CSS..

So you have:

```
.base_color {
  color: red;
}

.theme_color{

 color: blue;
}
```

Comment: This seems to make the most sense as an alternate to using !important, but perhaps just including the specific color stylesheets after the main one is the easiest way to go about it.

Comment: I agree Josh that is possible, however it would be better not to hide the original css class. For Example rather than override and hide, I'd rather create a new class for those specific cases, for example. Say you want 3 paragraphs to have the original color and one to be overriden in the theme..you'd  want the two classes there, otherwise you're actually hiding the original class..

Comment: Agreed, I think creating a new base class is the correct way to go about it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should never use `!important` unless you don't absolutely need it. I've never encountered a case that justifies it.

You can just include the alternate stylesheet after the main one and the colors will be overwritten anyway. No need for `!important`.

Also, read this: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: `!important` is part of the tools provided by CSS. It'll very very often complicate the future of a project but *not* always. I've encountered many cases where it's useful: if you're using "utility classes" like `.pa0 {padding: 0 !important}`, you don't need to override it; if it isn't what is needed, well you wouldn't have put an HTML class in the first place. Also in RWD desktop first: in the <320px MQ which is the smallest resolution and the last MQ, the classes you're writing won't be overriden by other MQ or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Just include the color scheme files after the base scheme. Like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="base.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="schemeX.css">
```

That way the latter styles override the base styles. Just use the same classes and ids on both files.